# Sorting ng-repeat elements dynamically according to date

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to order by elements according to date.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in PortfolioIdeaList | orderBy:'CreatedDate'" style="background-color:rgb(25, 26, 0);" ng-click="ShowIdeaDetails(item.Id)">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col col-80">
                   <p> {{item.Title}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-20">
                   <b> {{item.Status}}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col col-70">
                    {{item.CreatedDate}}
                </div>
                <div class="col col-30">
                    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ion-item>
```

I am getting Title,Created Date and Status from webservices in JSON format.
Created Date is coming as String format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS e.g 6/2/1991 2:33:43 PM or 12/23/2015 11:55:12 AM.
but its not ordering properly.
How to convert string into date and then order it.

Comment: Best way to do is to get the sorted data from the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OrderBy Date values, which are just strings in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306216/orderby-date-values-which-are-just-strings-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 2):

With your code, if CreatedDate is a string, your objects will be orderBy alphanumerical order.

If you want to order by date, you can :

- Convert this property to Date when you get your objects from the server

  ```
     new Date(item.CreatedDate)
  ```
- Create a custom filter who convert values into Date and order it :

  ```
  .filter("customOrderBy", function () {
       return function (input) {
      input.sort(function(a,b){
          return new Date(a.CreatedDate) > new Date(b.CreatedDate);
      });
      return input;
  }
  });
  ```

  And call it in your template :

  ```
  ng-repeat="item in PortfolioIdeaList | customOrderBy"
  ```

But in all case, you need to convert your strings to YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: But what if we have the date coming from database as 2/22/2015 2:33:44 PM

Comment: You have two solutions : 

You can create your own parser to create a Date : see example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10430381/3042398) or you can use an helper library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `:false` after `orderBy` works for me

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in PortfolioIdeaList | orderBy:'CreatedDate':false" style="background-color:rgb(25, 26, 0);" ng-click="ShowIdeaDetails(item.Id)">
```